# How to see if in-between two date columns, specific dates fall into, pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame({'date_start' : ['2022-12-06', '2022-12-25', '2022-12-16'],
              'date_end': ['2022-12-08', '2022-12-26', '2022-12-30']})

date_start  date_end
0   2022-12-06  2022-12-08
1   2022-12-25  2022-12-26
2   2022-12-16  2022-12-30
```

I would like to create an extra column that indicates if **between** `date_start` and `date_end` **at least one** of the `dates_xmas = ['2022-12-24','2022-12-25']` exist

The output dataframe should look like this:

```
pd.DataFrame({'date_start' : ['2022-12-06', '2022-12-25', '2022-12-16'],
              'date_end': ['2022-12-08', '2022-12-26', '2022-12-30'],
              'xmas':[0,1,1]})

date_start  date_end    xmas
0   2022-12-06  2022-12-08  0
1   2022-12-25  2022-12-26  1
2   2022-12-16  2022-12-30  1
```

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly the described logic, but assuming the dates are consecutive (it is here), you can use two masks using the min and max in two comparisons:

```
df['xmas'] = (df['date_start'].le('2022-12-25') # compare start to max
            & df['date_end'].ge('2022-12-24')   # compare end to min
             ).astype(int)
```

If the dates are not necessarily consecutive and you want to perform all comparisons, then use [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) broadcasting:

```
m1 = df['date_start'].to_numpy()[:,None] <= dates_xmas
m2 = df['date_end'].to_numpy()[:,None] >= dates_xmas

df['xmas'] = (m1&m2).any(axis=1).astype(int)
```

Output:

```
   date_start    date_end  xmas
0  2022-12-06  2022-12-08     0
1  2022-12-25  2022-12-26     1
2  2022-12-16  2022-12-30     1
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like some form of inequality join - if that is the case, you can use [conditional_join](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.conditional_join.conditional_join) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/) to get your results - this can be faster than a broadcasting - depending on the data size:

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor

df = df.transform(pd.to_datetime)
dates_xmas = pd.Series(pd.to_datetime(['2022-12-24','2022-12-25']), name = 'xmas')
(df
.conditional_join(
    dates_xmas, 
    # column from left, column from right, comparator
    ('date_start', 'xmas', '<='), 
    ('date_end', 'xmas', '>='), 
    # depending on the data size,
    # you might get more performance with numba
    use_numba=False,
    how = 'left', 
    # with an inequality join, you may get multiple matches
    # however, for this use case, you are only interested 
    # in one match per row
    keep='first')
.assign(xmas = lambda f: np.where(f.xmas.isna(), 0, 1))
)
  date_start   date_end  xmas
0 2022-12-25 2022-12-26     1
1 2022-12-16 2022-12-30     1
2 2022-12-06 2022-12-08     0
```

Another option is to just use `pd.merge_asof` - no need to import another library:

```py
(pd
.merge_asof(
    df.sort_values('date_start'), 
    dates_xmas, 
    left_on = 'date_start', 
    right_on = 'xmas', 
    direction='forward')
.assign(xmas = lambda f: f.xmas.between(f.date_start, f.date_end).astype(np.int8))
) 
  date_start   date_end  xmas
0 2022-12-06 2022-12-08     0
1 2022-12-16 2022-12-30     1
2 2022-12-25 2022-12-26     1
```